# Is it possible to filter the GMSPlacePicker based on place type/category

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-places-api

Using the new google places api for ios, is it possible to filter the results returned via GMSPlacePicker based on place type/category. For example, if I want to return all the gas_station types nearby.

Basically, I'm looking for something like GMSAutocompleteFilter, but for GMSPlacePicker.

Comment: I dont think the Google Places iOS SDK can do filter by types for you yet. But you can do a HTTP [Nearby Search Request](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search#PlaceSearchRequests), in the request parameter you can set the `types=gas_station`. In iOS, you can use `NSURLSession` to do a http request.

Comment: Thanks @ztan I look into that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a [HTTP Nearby Search Request](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search#PlaceSearchRequests), in the request parameter you can set the `types=gas_station`. In iOS, you can use `NSURLSession` to do a http request.

Sample code:

```
  let requestURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=2000&types=gas_station&key=YOUR_API_KEY"
  let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:requestURL)!)
  let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
  session.dataTaskWithRequest(request,
      completionHandler: {(data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) in

            if error == nil {
                let object = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
                println(object)

                let routes = object["results"] as! [NSDictionary]
                for route in routes {
                    println(route["name"])
                }
                }
                else {
                    println("Places API error")
                }

    }).resume()
```

This request will return the `gas_station` within 1000 meters near `-33.8670522,151.1957362`.

Comment: are there any issues using the places webservice api inside of an app? Reason I ask is the documentation suggest the webservice is intended for server applications. Thanks!

Comment: The iOS SDK cant do filter by types now(no such method available yet), so you have to use web service, there is no issues for it, but you have to perform `NSURLSession` instead of calling SDK methods directly.