# Remove/Edit markers on Google Places API?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I want to incorporate Google Places API in my projects and I want to edit the markers that the Google Places API provides for you. Here is a link displaying how the API works: https://developers.google.com/places/ios/placepicker. However, I want to be able to edit the red markers and change them to other types of images as opposed to having them as the built-in markers that Google has provided. The reason I see this is possible is because I looked at https://developers.google.com/maps/showcase/#ios and found that the project Foodspotter has changed the markers into those of different images. Would there be a way to edit the Places API to do this or would I have to do something like https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/marker to change the appearance of the markers? Thanks!

Edit: My Attempt:

```
@IBAction func pickPlace(sender: UIButton) {
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude)
    let northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude + 0.001, center.longitude + 0.001)
    let southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude - 0.001, center.longitude - 0.001)
    let viewport = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: northEast, coordinate: southWest)
    let config = GMSPlacePickerConfig(viewport: viewport)

    var camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude,
        longitude: locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 6)
    var mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
    self.view = mapView

    println("Going into place picker")
    placePicker?.pickPlaceWithCallback({ (place: GMSPlace?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        println("Inside Callback")
        if let error = error {
            println("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        if let place = place {
            self.nameLabel.text = place.name
            self.addressLabel.text = "\n".join(place.formattedAddress.componentsSeparatedByString(", "))

            var marker: GMSMarker = GMSMarker(position: self.locationManager.location.coordinate)
            marker.position = place.coordinate
            marker.title = place.name
            marker.snippet = place.formattedAddress
            marker.map = mapView;
            marker.icon = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "test")
            //marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker"];

            var cameraView = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(marker.position.latitude, longitude: marker.position.longitude, zoom: 6)
            mapView.animateToCameraPosition(cameraView)

        } else {
            self.nameLabel.text = "No place selected"
            self.addressLabel.text = ""
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: You already have the answer in your link you have exactly to do as te third link suggests to update the marker.                                                   GMSMarker *london = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
london.title = @"London";
london.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"house"];
london.map = mapView_;

Comment: @Qazi when I use the Google Place API however, I don't seem to have any GMSMarker objects I can use or edit which is my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GMSPlace` object returned from the `pickPlaceWithCallBack` method contains a `@property(nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;` property. You can use that to construct your `GMSMarker` object.

When you want to add a custom image to your `GMSMarker` object, you can just simply call `marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR_IMAGE_NAME"];`.

Sample code below:

```
-(void)testPlacePicker {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.5108396, -0.0922251);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude + 0.001, center.longitude + 0.001);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude - 0.001, center.longitude - 0.001);
    GMSCoordinateBounds *viewport = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithCoordinate:northEast
                                                                         coordinate:southWest];
    GMSPlacePickerConfig *config = [[GMSPlacePickerConfig alloc] initWithViewport:viewport];
    _placePicker = [[GMSPlacePicker alloc] initWithConfig:config];

    [_placePicker pickPlaceWithCallback:^(GMSPlace *place, NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Pick Place error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            return;
        }

        if (place != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Place name %@", place.name);
            NSLog(@"Place address %@", place.formattedAddress);
            NSLog(@"Place attributions %@", place.attributions.string);

            GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
            marker.position = place.coordinate;
            marker.title = place.name;
            marker.snippet = place.formattedAddress;
            marker.map = mapView_;
            marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker"];

            GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:marker.position.latitude
                                                                   longitude:marker.position.longitude
                                                                        zoom:6];

            [mapView_ animateToCameraPosition:camera];

        } else {
            NSLog(@"No place selected");
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! I think I understand everything but there's just one question I have: where does the `marker.map = mapView_` come from? I am trying to find this but I can't really find it in the code..

Comment: Doing `marker.map = mapView_;` just add a marker to your Google Map View. see this documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#step_6_add_a_map

Comment: Hi, Sorry just one other question. Thanks for helping me by the way. I tried to include your implementation of the markers but unfortunately my code doesn't even enter the `pickPlaceWithCallback` callback function anymore. I placed a print statement right after the `pickPlaceWithCallback` as seen above but it never gets executed.. any ideas why?

Comment: Did you call `placePiclker = GMSPlacePicker(config: config)` to initialize your place picker?

Comment: Ah okay I did not do that. Thanks! Another question I have then: I want to remove the places that Google has provided using the Places API. For example, if you select a coordinate, it will show you restaurants, addresses, and certain places that are near that coordinate. Rather, I want to have a user input a place and have that place show up on the map. Would the Places API be best to use for this or the Maps API is better?

Comment: You should use [Place Autocomplete API](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/autocomplete?hl=en)

Comment: Yes but for the map portion of what I want to do, would the best be to edit the Places API or to use the Maps API? I'm thinking the Maps API seems better since the Places API comes with extra markers and such that I may not need since it's all user input..

Comment: The Place Autocomplete API will give you JSON http response, you can parse the JSON. Based on the response, you can choose one of the items from the JSON response list, and make it a marker.

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying. My issue is this: I take a user-input Place via the Autocomplete API and make it a marker, I only want to display those user-input Places and not all of the ones that Google provides. Any way to do this? I found the following link which is pretty much what I want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791106/is-it-possible-to-filter-the-gmsplacepicker-based-on-place-type-category  but I don't know where to put this NSURLSession in combination with the `pickPlaceWithCallback`.